# Moving Text Up Inside CSS Background Image

Tags: html, css, background-image

Usually I'm pretty on the ball with CSS and able to figure most of it out, however this has got me stumped.

Basically on our widget, the text in the 'Click Here' button needs to be moved up so there is an equal gap above and below that text (in relation to the red box).

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="setLocation('amplifiers/pioneer-appradio-2-sph-da100.html/index.htm')" class="button btn-cart" title="Shop NOW" type="button">
<span><span>Click Here</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.banner button {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
.banner button span {
    background: transparent url(../images/media/slider_button_bg.png) 0 0 no-repeat!important;
    height: 24px;
    padding-left: 12px;
}
.banner button span span {
    background-position: 100% 0!important;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding- right: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

The website in question is http://foscam-uk.com/index.php if you wish to see what I am asking.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: although not related to queeastion . but your website use lots of javascripts . Tty to combine into one.

Comment: Indeed, this will all be combined before the site goes live. Thanks for the comment though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't quite get your code to work (I think it may be missing something from the rest of your css). But you should be able to center it by setting the `line-height` the same as the container height (24px in this case).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use span for that. 
Try to make button backgrounds through css only as it will reduce the  useless http requests.

```
    <button onclick="setLocation('speakers/pioneer-ts-g172ci.html/index.htm')" 
    class="button btn-cart" id="thisPartButton" title="Shop NOW" type="button">
Click Here</button>
```

And css for this particular button can be made

```
#thisPartButton{
color:white;
background:#CE0B08;  //replace it with your image
padding:7px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another style that is used in your page beyond what you pasted here that is causing the vertical placement of the button text to be where it is.

`button.btn-cart span`  (in line 203 of your styles.css) has `line-height:31px;`

Reduce that line-height (25px looked reasonable in my local test) to correct the text placement.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not tell the span with text to be relative and place it at proper coordinates?

Or even margin-top / margin-bottom?

Otherwise, for vertical aligning, try [here](http://www.vertical-align.com/).